# Bootstrap 4 is breaking Stripe Elements

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate  Stripe with my Laravel site

in order to do this I am following the documentation on their website

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

I can get to work with no errors, but something in bootstrap 4 is affecting the styling. If I drop the dependancy to a pre bootstrap 4 version it works.

This is what it looks like with bootstrap 4
[image: BrokenInput]

and this is what is should look like and this is running with bootstrap 3

[image]

I have created two bootply examples to demostrate the issue

Broken Example

https://www.bootply.com/Tqz93y47Qe

Working Example

https://www.bootply.com/EvYkmKUPM3

Is there away to get stripe to ignore the bootstrap styling?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `flex-column` class with `form-row`

https://www.bootply.com/t8jij8fQOp

`form-row` is display flex and flex-direction row by default. Change it to flex-direction column using `flex-column` class

**OR**

Use **w-100** class on `card-element`. It will give 100% width to that element

Updated [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/4oiOMbavTd)

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: Lifesaver! How the heck did you find that? The stripe content is so nested (within an iframe even) I didn't have any luck using DevTools to debug it.

Comment: @GregBell Thanks and please upvote if this answer helped you :)

Comment: Damn! you have saved my time!

Answer (score 0):

you have to just remove "form-row" class. use there "d-block" class. "form-row" is bootstrap-4 default class that's why it messed up.

I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but resolved it remove `form-row` class and use `flex-column` and in div with id `card-element` add the class `w-100`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to integrate Stripe payments with a bootstrap + create react web app, and these solutions didn't work. The official documentation prescribes the following code:

```
function CardSection() {
  return (
    <label>
      Card details
      <CardElement options={CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS} />
    </label>
  );
};
```

This code resulted in a squished input box for me that would not respond to bootstrap utility classes such as `.w-100` or `.container`. However, shifting the `CardElement` component outside of the `<label>` above fixes the problem:

```
function CardSection() {
  return (
    <>
      <label>Card details</label>
      <CardElement options={CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS} />
    </>
  );
}
```