# Laravel Won't Load Stripe Elements from Stripe Docs

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying a simple Stripe API implementation on my Laravel app, and for some reason, I cannot get the Elements to load. I have copy and pasted direct from the Docs, a simple form with an element and for the life of me, I can't figure out why it will not load.

Everything **seems** to be in order. 
- My JS files are in the public directory 
- I have tried with scripts  NOT defered 
- I have tried hard coding into one page 
- I have read through the Docs seemingly 10 times 
- I have checked line by line to make sure the id tags are the same as referenced in the js files.

So far, I am at a loss. I have been working on this for a few hours and I'm just staring at the screen baffled at this point. Any ninjas around who can spot a likely rookie mistake I've made? Here are my current files:

app.blade.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Springs Fat to Fit</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" defer></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/stripe.js')}}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" defer></script>

    <script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}" defer ></script>




    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">


     @if(Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->is_admin == 0)
     @include('partials.navbar')
        @else @if(Auth::user()->is_admin == 1)
        @include('partials.admin_navbar')
        @endif
     @endif



        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

testPage.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

<form action="{{route('testPage')}}" method="post" id="payment-form">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-row">


            <label for="card-element">
            Credit or debit card
          </label>
          <div id="card-element">
            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
          </div>

          <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
          <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

        </div>

        <button>Submit Payment</button>
      </form>


</div>  {{-- This is the end of the container--}}
@endsection
```

stripe.js:

```
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key right here');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
    base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4'
        }
    },
    invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error.
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            // Send the token to your server.
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
    });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: please check your browser console log, see if there's exception.

Comment: any solution? If I remove the app.css file the form loads, but it look awful..

Comment: Not sure if it is really the same problem. But at least for Laravel 5.8 please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53497323/359100. It solved my issue. (And since I hit this SO question during search I add this reference.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to rule out your errors.

1. rule out whether if it's js error or not:  please check your browser console log, network tab, etc, see if there's exception. see if your js is loaded. see all your required js are loaded, not showing 404.
2. put breakpoints on your js on chrome dev tools. put a lot of them on your switch blocks, if blocks,etc.
3. fix if you find any problem.
4. make sure stripe assets is not blocked by your chrome plugins e,g. adblocks
5. check api keys / secrets if there's any